# StreamReader and TextReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to read from a pbx file using StreamReader, edit the contents and display the contents to a new file using TextReader in c#.

This is my first developement task in a c#.

I studied java at uni and my new job uses c#.

Basically I have to read through a list of records contained in a pbx file from a phone system. These records however, have a line of good call records followed by a line with a few dodgy characters, followed by another line of good records.

My task is to read through this file line by line and then write a piece of code to ignore the lines with dodgy characters and output the good records into a new file on my c:\ drive which ive called output.txt.

I can write the while loop to take out the dodgy characters but im unsure of the c# code to read from the pbx file on my c drive and then output the edited contents to a new file called output.txt, also on my c drive.

I'm new to c# and have explored google for hours on this. Just need a little guidance and I'm away...

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would be much easier to help you if you posted some of the code that you started writing: we could probably spot an error or two much faster than helping you write this from scratch.

Comment: A workaround for "dodgy" requires a solid definition of "dodgy".  With some odds that they are not dodgy at all but just a side-effect of reading the file with the wrong encoding.  Start by looking at the file content with a hex viewer so you can see the actual byte values and discover a pattern.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention the file encodings, so I'm sticking with the UTF-8 defaults here.

One option is the 'regular' method of a loop that reads, checks, and conditionally writes, like this:

```
var inputFilePath  = @"C:\temp\input.txt";
var outputFilePath = @"C:\temp\output.txt";

using (var reader = File.OpenText(inputFilePath))
using (var writer = File.CreateText(outputFilePath))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var isValidLine = CheckLine(line);
        if (isValidLine)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you tagged this VS2008, I'm guessing that means you're limited to .NET 3.5, but on 4.0 or later, you can read and write enumerables and then leverage that (in .NET 3.5 you'd have to read all the lines into memory, filter, then write all the lines).

```
var inputFilePath  = @"C:\temp\input.txt";
var outputFilePath = @"C:\temp\output.txt";

var inputLines = File.ReadLines(inputFilePath);

var linesToWrite = inputLines
    .Where(line => IsLineValid(line));

File.WriteAllLines(outputFilePath, linesToWrite);
```

Comment: Sticking with the default is a very likely reason for the OP's trouble.  The odds that a PBX log file was written in utf8 are *very* low.  At least recommend and show usage for Encoding.Default